# Environment for print Capture on AWS GLUE

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, jobs, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

Where can I see, for example, the prints that are written in my AWS GLUE script? Like a terminal screen that shows me the messages that were stored in a print. I need to print the schema being generated for my data output and see if it matches what I need and understand where my script is breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print statements are captured in CloudWatch logs

You can view them in the Console by clicking the Logs link in the History tab

[image]

Comment: I understand. In this case for me to be able to visualize, for example, my schema I just put DataSource.printSchema()

Excuse my ignorance, but I'm still in the learning process. thanks for the comprehension