# Where to find printSchema() logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Where can I find logs of df.printSchema() function in aws glue when running job?

Run of job is successful but I can't find anywhere schema being printed

Comment: Have you checked the logs? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71785384/3437504

Comment: Your driver and worker nodes have separate log streams. I believe that `df.printSchema()` runs on the driver, but you should check both types. It would probably help if you added a `print("schema should follow")` debug message in your code.